# AJAX returns regular JSON but when I use an object it won't return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

All of my SQL code and stuff works, like I said, it works fine if

```
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['message'] = $rows1;
    echo json_encode($jTableResult);
```

was

```
$jTableResult = array($rows1);
echo json_encode($jTableResult);
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#alertbut").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../ajax/ajax.php?key=8789789fdgjhl',
            //data:dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (s) {
                //alert(s);
                $( "#alerts" ).empty();
                $('#alerts').append($.parseJSON(s[0]));
            }


        });
      });
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
if($key == "8789789fdgjhl")
{
$getalerts = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM alerts LIMIT 5");
$getalerts->execute();
$rows = array();
while($row = $getalerts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $rows1[] = $row['user'];

}
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['message'] = $rows1;
    echo json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON is already parsed when you receive it to your `success` function as you've told the ajax call that the expected dataType is `json`. Therefore `$.parseJSON()` is going to turn your object into a string of single digit characters, such as `[object Object]`, so you will get `o` in your case.

Change it.

```
$('#alerts').append(s[0]);
```

Should give you what you expect if the returned array has a key of `s` with an array at the index of 0.

**Edit**

Given the link you supplied, you actually have an array that holds a collection of names at the index of `message`. Please use the following:

```
$('alerts').append(s.message[0]);
```

Comment: @SerenityJosh Copy + paste the returned JSON encoded string into a pastebin/jsfiddle, etc, and give us the link.

Comment: (http://pastebin.com/KHYtdNwY) this is the link, the names are just SQL results from a table.